# How do I operate on a list of lists of tuples?

Tags: list, haskell

I have something that looks like this:

```
[[('A',2), ('C',0), ('G',0), ('T',0)]
,[('A',0), ('C',2), ('G',0), ('T',0)]
,[('A',0), ('C',0), ('G',2), ('T',0)]
,[('A',0), ('C',0), ('G',0), ('T',2)]]
```

I want to do operations on the second element of every tuple. I want to divide them by a certain number, so that it becomes a double.

I've tried using maps, so I can print just the second element of the tuples with

```
map (map snd) f
```

where `f` is the list above. I get the following:

```
[[2,0,0,0],[0,2,0,0],[0,0,2,0],[0,0,0,2]]
```

I'm really stuck now; I can't seem to figure out what to do next and how to do operations on those.

Comment: What sort of operations do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it. I want to divide them by a certain number. @JHobern

Comment: So you want a list of all of the second elements, divided by some number?

Comment: Yes, a list list. @JHobern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use two maps, one map for traversing the outer list, and the other map for traversing the inner list. Some demo in `ghci` to make it clear:

```
λ> let x = [[('A',2),('C',0),('G',0),('T',0)],[('A',0),('C',2),('G',0),('T',0)]]
λ> map (map id) x
[[('A',2),('C',0),('G',0),('T',0)],[('A',0),('C',2),('G',0),('T',0)]]
λ> map (\y -> map id y) x
[[('A',2),('C',0),('G',0),('T',0)],[('A',0),('C',2),('G',0),('T',0)]]
λ> map (\y -> map (\(a,b) -> (a,b)) y) x
[[('A',2),('C',0),('G',0),('T',0)],[('A',0),('C',2),('G',0),('T',0)]]
λ> map (\y -> map (\(a,b) -> (a,b * 8)) y) x
[[('A',16),('C',0),('G',0),('T',0)],[('A',0),('C',16),('G',0),('T',0)]]
```

Notice that the first three examples written above are equivalent. Notice how I expand each one of them. `id` is an identity function which will return the same output as input. In the last `map` expression, I apply an `* 8` to the second value of the tuple. Likewise, you implement your custom operation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, really appreciate it :)
But when I divide the numbers in my list I get an error `No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from the literal`. I want them to be of type Double.

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 The type system is complaining that you are trying to divide `Int` by `Fractional` component. Try doing:  `fromIntegral(b) / 8.0` something like this which will perform the proper conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it. And thanks for also explaining through ghci how it works :)

Answer (score 4):

The [`Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html) module exposes a [`second`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:second) function which you could use:

```
λ: let xs = [[('A',2), ('C',0), ('G',0), ('T',0)]]
λ: map (map (second (/ 3))) xs
[[('A',0.6666666666666666),('C',0.0),('G',0.0),('T',0.0)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens):

```
λ: import Control.Lens
λ: import Control.Lens.Traversal
λ: let input = [[('A',2)],[('G',0),('T',1)]]
λ: over (mapped.mapped._2) ((/ 4).fromIntegral) input
[[('A',0.5)],[('G',0.0),('T',0.25)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list that consists of all of the second elements in your tuples, you can flatten your lists, using `concat`, and then `map snd` over that new list. This will give you a list composed of all of the second elements of your tuples.

```
secondElements = map snd . concat
```

This will give you a list of all of the second elements in your tuples, and you can then map your functions over it.